# What uses does a binary search have in competitive programming, other than simply finding the location of a value in a container?

Tags: java, c++, containers, binary-search

Looking at the solutions for various competitive programming tasks that I could not solve, I saw that using a binary search was a key component of the solution, yet I cannot see why it was even used in the first place. I only know that binary search can be used to find the location of a value inside a container. What other practical uses, besides this, commonly found in competitive programming tasks, does binary search have?

Comment: You have a sorted list of one billion numbers.  Go find out if a number exists in this list.  How would you find this number?  Go one by one in the list until the number is found?

Comment: Yes, but more task specific applications, not just the basic ones

Comment: That *is* a specific task.  A sorted list of items and you want to find yes or no if an item exists.  The real world consists of sorted lists.  Also, this is what algorithms are about.  Binary search is one of the fundamental algorithms you have to know.

Comment: Oh, and if you're a fan of the "Price is Right" game show, the "clock game" is easily won each time by using binary search to find the price of the item shown.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used in interactive questions. You will be allowed to ask at max Q questions of the form - 'is greater than x?', 'is less than x?' or 'is equal to x' to ask and depending upon the outputs of the judge, you will have to figure out the number.